# npm install mysql: No compatible version found: mysql@5.7.13

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

When I try to install mysql using npm, the error displayed is No compatible versions found. Mysql installed is the latest version, however it is asking very old versions which are compatible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMEU9.jpg)

Pls provide help.

Comment: General tip: typically you shouldn't install modules like that to `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Comment: @mscdex Then how should I install?

Comment: Usually you would create a separate directory for your project (e.g. `C:\myproject` or wherever else is convenient).

Comment: @mscdex, did the same still unable to get it installed

Comment: There are no such version of node module  - mysql. All you need is npm i mysql@2.11.1 . This will install latest version of module, which is not realted to the version of  MySQL (RDBMS)